# ConstraintLayout ListView RTL some lines are not RTL

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left, android-constraintlayout

On my **ListView** some lines are not **RTL aligned**.
After **scrolling** and redrawing the lines are correct.

My layout of the line item:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/clFrontView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCircle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/circle"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivReminderType"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivCircle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivCircle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivCircle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivCircle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ivCircle"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ivCircle" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civContactImage"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icivCircleSmall"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/civContactImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/civContactImage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/civContactImage"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTextLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="Line of Text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ivCircle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivCircle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTextLine2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTextLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="Wed, 01.05.2018 10:10"
        android:textColor="#FF909090"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTextLine2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRepeat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="Every 2nd Friday"
        android:textColor="#FF909090"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTime" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

First start it looks like this, the first line is not RTL:
[image]

After scrolling down and again up to the top it is correct:
[image]

build.gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

Comment: I think, you can fix it by removing all `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' and `  app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf' and make sure equivalent `app:layout_constraintLeft_toStartOf` and `app:layout_constraintLeft_toEndOf` is there!..

Comment: @Pzy64: I have already Start_toStartOf and End_toEndOf in my layout. Why should I add "Left_toStartOf"? I don't know what this should be. Left is not if you want RTL instead it should be Start_toStartOf. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Ok, I mean Remove all`toLeft` of `toRight`, if the layout breaks add the equivalent `toStart` or `toEnd` or whatever. Basically when you  write `Left` or `Right`, it just stay left or right overriding the RTL Bevavior. If you  want your code to be completely obey RTL behavior, you may need to remove every attribute that spectify left or right and replace with start or endunless you really want!!.. There may be case where you want a button to be at rightside of Edittext  even if RTL or not, In that case you can specify Right or Left. .. (correct me if im wrong..)

Comment: OK I understand, but my problem is that ONLY some lines in the ListView are not right to left. After scrolling it is right to left. So it is not a general problem. Anyway I have the same problem if I remove all toLeft and toRight. :-(

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: The solution which one of my team member applied was to define a separate layout for rtl (in layout-ar in our case as we are supporting Arabic) and paste this line in theConstraintLayout tag: android:layoutDirection="rtl". It fixes the issue, but it's an ugly patch

Comment: Also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696154/listview-layout-inconsistent-rendering-with-rtl-languages-arabic#comment97697859_49696154) but the OP is using a LinearLayout there. I'll try to create an issue for google, if nobody has done it yet.

Comment: The same problem, I think I have to use 'LinearLayout' inside 'ConstraintLayout'

Answer (score 0):

These changes may work:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivCircle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_circle_win"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/civContactImage"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/civContactImage"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivReminderType"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/civContactImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/civContactImage"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/civContactImage"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icivCircleSmall"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/civContactImage"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/civContactImage"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/civContactImage"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTextLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/civContactImage"
    tools:text="Line of Text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTextLine2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#FF909090"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/civContactImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTextLine"
    tools:text="Wed, 01.05.2018 10:10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRepeat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#FF909090"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/civContactImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTime"
    tools:text="Every 2nd Friday" />
```

I hope to work. good luck

Comment: No, the same problem :-(

Comment: Remove all `rtl` or `ltr` direction attr for all parents. It seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe it could solve the problem. Small testing changes are there you can remove them according to your need, Firstly, I have changed the tools:text to android:text so that it shows dummy data.Secondly, The two imageview named as **ivReminderType** and **icivCircleSmall** I have put two default images just for testing purpose so do change that. Also there is one imageview named **icivCircleSmall** I didnt know where it should be constarined to so I have not edited any code written for it. Below is the edited code of the xml.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clFrontView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCircle"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvRepeat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvTime"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTextLine"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivReminderType"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvRepeat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvRepeat"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTime"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civContactImage"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icivCircleSmall"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/civContactImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/civContactImage"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/civContactImage"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTextLine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Line of Text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/civContactImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/civContactImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTextLine2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTextLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Wed, 01.05.2018 10:10"
        android:textColor="#FF909090"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/civContactImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTextLine2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRepeat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Every 2nd Friday"
        android:textColor="#FF909090"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvTime"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvTextLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTime" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope it helps!